# How to write a Python script that uses the OpenERP ORM to directly upload to Postgres Database

Tags: odoo

I need to write a "standalone" script in Python to upload sales taxes to the account_tax table in the database using ONLY the ORM module of OpenERP. What I would like to do is something like the pseudo code below.

Can someone provide me a more details on the following:
1) what sys.path's do I need to set
2) what modules do I need to import before importing the "account" module. Currently when I import the "account" module I get the following error:
AssertionError: The report "report.custom" already exists!
3) What is the proper way to get my database cursor. In the code below I am simply calling psycopg2 directly to get a cursor.

If this approach cannot work, can anyone suggest an alternative approach other than writing XML files to load the data from the OpenERP application itself. This process needs to run outside of the the standard OpenERP application.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
import sys
# set Python paths to access openerp modules
sys.path.append("./openerp")
sys.path.append("./openerp/addons")

# import OpenERP 
import openerp

# import the account addon modules that contains the tables 
# to be populated.
import account

# define connection string
conn_string2 = "dbname='test2' user='xyz' password='password'"

# get a db connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string2)

# conn.cursor() will return a cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

# and finally use the ORM to insert data into table.
```

Comment: hi Tim you want to use only ORM as module or you want OE Service to insert data without using UI ???

Answer (score 16):

If you wanna do it via web service then have look at the  [OpenERP XML-RPC Web services](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html)

Example code top work with OpenERP Web Services :

```
import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' #the user
pwd = 'admin'      #the password of the user
dbname = 'test'    #the database

# OpenERP Common login Service proxy object 
sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

#replace localhost with the address of the server
# OpenERP Object manipulation service 
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

partner = {
   'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
   'lang': 'fr_FR',
}
#calling remote ORM create method to create a record 
partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)
```

More clearly you can also use the [OpenERP Client lib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp-client-lib/1.0.3)
Example Code with client lib :

```
import openerplib

connection = openerplib.get_connection(hostname="localhost", database="test", \
    login="admin", password="admin")
user_model = connection.get_model("res.users")
ids = user_model.search([("login", "=", "admin")])
user_info = user_model.read(ids[0], ["name"])
print user_info["name"]
```

You see both way are good but when you use the client lib, code is less and easy to understand while using xmlrpc proxy is lower level calls that you will handle
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In using openerplib, is there a way to query the database with plain ole SQL statements?  If so, is there a way to obtain the database cursor on which to execute the SQL query?

Comment: Hello, Tim using some web service you can not directly call the sql trigger but their is always way out. In Some model you write function with sql triggers then using model service you can trigger the that function which triggers the sql.

Comment: How do I find out the name of the database?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the xmlrpc call of openerp. 
it will not need to import account or openerp . and even you can have all orm functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As per my view one must go for `XMLRPC` or `NETSVC` services provided by Open ERP for such needs.

You don't need to import `accounts` module of Open ERP, there are possibilities that other modules have inherited `accounts.tax` object and had altered its behaviour as per your business needs.

Eventually if you feed data by calling those methods manually without using Open ERP `Web service` its possible you'll get undesired result / unexpected failures / inconsistent database state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Erppeek](http://erppeek.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to browse data, but not sure if you can really upload data to DB, personally I use/prefer XMLRPC

Answer (score 0):

You can use python library to access openerp server using xmlrpc service. 
Please check https://github.com/OpenERP/openerp-client-lib

It is officially supported by OpenERP SA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interacti directly with the DB, you could just **import psycopg2** and:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', user='dbuser', password='dbpassword', host='dbhost')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from table where id = %d' % table_id)
cur.execute('insert into table(column1, column2) values(%d, %d)' % (value1, value2))
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you want to fix it like that?! You should create a **localization module** and define data in **XML files**. This is the standard way to fix such a problem in OpenERP.

You want to insert sales taxes for which country? Explain more plz.

Answer (score -1):

from openerp.modules.registry import RegistryManager
registry = RegistryManager.get("databasename")
with registry.cursor() as cr:
         user = registry.get('res.users').browse(cr, userid, listids)
         print user