# OpenERP XML-RPC interface and object definition / interface

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

Does someone know where can I find the definition of the XML-RPC interfaces (in OpenERP 7)? I want to know which parameters and object attributes I need to create or get objects.  Examples of the XML for every element would also be very helpful.

Comment: might be this helpful to you http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/xml-rpc-web-services-in-openerp.html

Answer (score 2):

You can always inspect objects interactively with [ERPpeek](https://erppeek.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

With this tool you can use Python REPL on any object and see its fields

Answer (score 1):

XMLRPC or NETSVC services are provided by OpenERP for such needs. Go through the [OpenERP XML-RPC Web services](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html/) document, which explains the protocol implementation.

More discussion is here: [How to write a Python script that uses the OpenERP ORM to directly upload to Postgres Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493578/how-to-write-a-python-script-that-uses-the-openerp-orm-to-directly-upload-to-pos)

Comment: Thanks firebug. I red the doc already, but i was not able to find a definition of the objects content and relation. It seems that i have to use the postgres elements.

Comment: @elCapitano When you use the XMLRPC Service, it return the values in specific lang formats, for example if I use python based XML RPC call it return me list of Dict where each element in dict is record with key to be field  name and values for the from db. now their multiple service provided by OE so you can call any service and youw ill get respective answer in it. and can you explain more what do you want as in `objects content` or what is exact intention, so we can be more specific on answer.